# Get data without identifiers

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

For a descriptive statistical analysis I need to grab the data a webpage.

One record looks like that:

```
<div class="space"></div>

    <p style="margin-bottom: -5px;">R110327</p>

    <h1>Test</h1>

    <div class="hline_index"></div>

    <p>TestProfession<br>
    city, street<br>
    Tel: 129128312 Serie, Fax: 214213413<br>
    Email: <a href="mailto:test">test</a><br>
    Web: <a href="test.at" target="_blank">http://www.test.at</a><br>
    <br>
    Language: English<br>
    Profession: meditation, sport<br></p>

    <div class="hline_index"></div>

    <div class="space"></div>
```

I am doing that with `selenium 2.42.2`. For testing purpose I tried to gather the `fullName, profession and the street`.

```
public ArrayList<Person> getWantedFields() {
    log.info("retrieve wanted fields");

    resultList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    WebElement fullName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1"));
    WebElement profession = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p"));
    WebElement street = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p/br[1]"));

    //2811 results
    for (int i = 0; i < 2811; i++) {
        resultList.add(new Person(fullName.getText(), profession.getText(), street.getText(), null, null, null, null, null));                   
    }

    log.info(resultList.toString());

    return resultList;
}
```

However, I only get back:

`[Person [fullName=Search, profession=, street=, ...`

As you can see only the first field gives me always the same text and the other two give me back "".

I think my `xpath` is wrong but I am struggeling to get the wanted fields, when I do not have identifiers.

Any recommendations how to get these three fields?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a few `<p>` elements **before** the one that you are trying to access.

All the elements that you actually want to access are under `<div id="content_head_folge">`.

So you should start each of the Xpaths that you are using with `//div[@id='content_head_folge']`.

---

```
List<WebElement> fullNames   = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='content_head_folge']/h1"));
List<WebElement> professions = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='content_head_folge']/p"));
List<WebElement> streets     = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='content_head_folge']/p/br[1]"));

//2811 results
for (int i = 0; i < 2811; i++)
    resultList.add(new Person(fullNames.get(i).getText(), professions.get(i).getText(), streets.get(i).getText(), null, null, null, null, null));
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! Could you probably show me by an example how to get the street. I do not get how to go deeper.

Comment: `street = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='content_head_folge']/p/br[1]"));`

Comment: @Vivien: I just noticed that you weren't even using a `List` of `WebElement` objects, so added that to the answer...